# Openlayers 4 WMS layer not showing after authentication

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, authentication

I'm new to OpenLayers and I have a problem I just cannot wrap my head around.

I'm trying to show a WMS layer from my GeoServer, but it passes through an authenticator I made with Flask. This definitely works, as I'm receiving 200 Response and the WMS server works fine with QGIS. 
It's not a CORS issue either as that's set to enable all at the moment.

In order to allow the authenticator to work, it needs to pass through customLoader to add the authentication headers on which is read by my Flask API. Which seems completely fine.

So my issue is that OpenLayers isn't displaying anything from my GeoServer and I really want that to work.

Response sent back to the request from my API:

```
RES:  <Response [200]>\r
HEADERS:  {'vary': 'Origin', 'X-Frame-Options': 'ALLOWALL', 'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename=OS_OpenData-ne_50m_admin_0_countries.png', 'Content-Type': 'image/png', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Date': 'Fri, 05 Jun 2020 10:34:24 GMT', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=20', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}\r
```

Now I've been pulling my hair out trying to get this to work with OpenLayers and this is what I have got so far:

```
<head>
<title>Tiled WMS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js? 
features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>

<script>
    function customLoader(tile, src) {
       var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
       client.open('GET', src);
       client.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + window.btoa('xxxxxxx' + ":" + 'xxxxxxxxx'));
       client.onload = function() {
       tile.getImage().src = src;
    };
    client.send();
  }
  var layers = [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:80/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/v1/wms',
        tileLoadFunction: customLoader,
        params: {'LAYERS': 'OS_OpenData:ne_50m_admin_0_countries', 'TILED': true},
        transparent:true
      }),
      format:'image/png'
    })
  ];
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0,0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you break the problem down to work out where the issue is? does GeoServer produce the map? does OL receive the image?

Comment: OL must receive something as when I zoom in and out and move the map around, I see more requests come in. Additionally, if I put a wrong file name in at the request, then GeoServer responds back with an error XML. And as the WMS works fine with QGIS, it must be an error inside my OL

Answer (score 5):

`tile.getImage().src = src;` is an unauthenticated load, you need to use the response from the xhr as a data url

```
function customLoader(tile, src) {
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.responseType = 'blob';
  client.open('GET', src);
  client.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + window.btoa('xxxxxxx' + ":" + 'xxxxxxxxx'));
  client.onload = function() {
    tile.getImage().src = URL.createObjectURL(client.response);
  };
  client.send();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mike. This has fixed the problem I have been so confused on for days! To clarify what you changed - in my previous code I wasn't doing anything with the response and so OpenLayers was just receiving a few headers that it didn't know what to do with, and now the createObjectURL has turned this into an Object which OpenLayers understands?

Comment: It's not specific to OpenLayers, you could do the same with any javascript or html image.  The xhr gets the remote data with authentication, in this case tile.getImage() returns the tile's javascript image object, then to display it you need to set the source for the local image to a data url based on what was read with authentication.