# Retrying failed XYZ tile load in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, tiles

I already had similar question about failed TileWMS retry ([Retrying failed TileWMS tile load in OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368119/retrying-failed-tilewms-tile-load-in-openlayers)), but this time I'm using different approach to solve the problem. Solution is based on the code I found in OpenLayers API docs, but I don't remember where.

I'm retrieving tiles from ArcGIS REST service which is not completely reliable. Quite often instead of image it returns error diagnose:

> ArcGIS Web Adaptor Could not access any server machines. Please
> contact your system administrator.

So I'm using custom `tileLoadFunction` where I detect if result of tile fetch is text, and in this case try to reload tile after 1 second. Here is the code:

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:3794',
           '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');                   
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

var proj3794 = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3794');
proj3794.setExtent([373611.333301285, 30999.929999999993, 623999.96, 194999.93]);

var tileGridRes3794 = [1322.9193125052918, 529.1677250021168, 396.87579375158754, 330.72982812632296, 264.5838625010584, 198.43789687579377, 132.2919312505292, 92.60435187537043, 66.1459656252646, 39.687579375158755, 26.458386250105836, 19.843789687579378, 13.229193125052918, 6.614596562526459, 3.9687579375158752, 2.6458386250105836, 1.9843789687579376, 1.3229193125052918, 0.6614596562526459, 0.26458386250105836];     
var viewGridRes3794 = tileGridRes3794.slice(5);

var mjuTopoSource = new ol.source.XYZ({
  url: 'https://gisserver.gov.si/arcgis/rest/services/TEMELJNE_KARTE/MJU_TOPO_KARTA/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
  tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
    origin: [-5122600.0, 5001100.0],
    extent: proj3794.getExtent(),
    tileSize: 256,
    resolutions: tileGridRes3794
  }),
  projection: proj3794,
  crossOrigin: '',
});

const retryCodes = [408, 429, 500, 502, 503, 504];
const retries = {};
mjuTopoSource.setTileLoadFunction((tile, src) => {
  const image = tile.getImage();
  console.log('tile load - fetch', tile, image, src);
  fetch(src)
    .then((response) => {
      if (retryCodes.includes(response.status)) {
        retries[src] = (retries[src] || 0) + 1;
        if (retries[src] <= 3) {
          setTimeout(() => tile.load(), retries[src] * 1000);
          console.log('retry 1', src, retries[src]);
        }
        return Promise.reject();
      }
      return response.blob();
    })
    .then((blob) => {
      if (blob.type == 'text/html') {
        retries[src] = (retries[src] || 0) + 1;
        if (retries[src] <= 3) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('retrying 2', src, retries[src]);
            tile.load();
          }, retries[src] * 5000);
          console.log('retry 2', src, retries[src]);
        }
        return Promise.reject();
      }
      const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      image.src = imageUrl;
      console.log('tile load - show', tile, image, src);
      setTimeout(() => URL.revokeObjectURL(imageUrl), 5000);
    })
    .catch(() => tile.setState(3)); // error
});

var mjuTopo = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source:  mjuTopoSource
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [mjuTopo],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([14.60, 46.12]),
    zoom: 8,
    maxZoom: 18,
  }),
});
```

Problem is that retried tile is not shown on the map, despite logs showing that tile was retrieved and assigned to the image source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dropping through to `Promise.reject()` after setting timeouts so the status will be error, you should return after calling `setTimeout`.  Also I am not sure if `tile.load()` has any effect if it is already loading.  It would be easier to do repeat fetches in a loop in an async function

```
tileLoadFunction: async (tile, src) => {
  const image = tile.getImage();
  let response;
  let attempts = 0;
  let valid = false;
  try {
    while (true) {
      attempts++;
      response = await fetch (src);
      valid = !retryCodes.includes(response.status) && !response.headers.get('content-type').includes('text/html');
      if (valid || attempts === 3) {
        break;
      }
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    }
    if (valid) {
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      image.addEventListener('load', () => URL.revokeObjectURL(imageUrl));
      image.src = imageUrl;
    } else {
      tile.setState(3);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    tile.setState(3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great, but had to do two changes to make it work for me (see edited answer). I'll try to find place in OL API docs from where I copied my code that does not work.

Comment: I took code for my try from here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_ImageTile-ImageTile.html

Comment: Setting status to error is necessary for tile.load() to attempt a reload.  That code (and yours) does work most of the time, but it sets new listeners at each attempt without removing the previous ones, which might be the cause of the problem.  https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/ImageTile.js#L144